# Ratio and Proportion.

Tags: arithmetic, rational-numbers

A girl went to market to buy brinjal,onion and coconut.........she gives
               
 Rs 2       and buys     40  brianjals
                
Rs 1       and buys     01  onion
                
Rs 5       and buys     01  coconut..........
                   ....................BUT...................
          The total amount of rupees spent  and the number of vegetables bought should be 100....

> Question: How many of each onion, brinjal, coconut  does the girl buy with the above prices so that the total rupees spent and the net quantity bought is exactly 100??

Example:-
 Rs  Quantity (indicative)
             2 $\quad$  40   Brinjals
             1 $\quad$  1     Onion
             5 $\quad$  1     Coconut
            --- ----
           100  100   ----> Expected sum(Once the quantities are provided by the solution)

Comment: What’s unclear about this? What’s desired is obviously a solution in non-negative integers to the system $$\left\{\begin{align*}&x+y+z=100\\&2x+y+5z=100\;.\end{align*}\right.$$ And the unique solution is clearly $x=z=0,y=100$: she buys $100$ onions, no brianjals, and no coconuts.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott why are the equations like this, for 2 rs she buys 40 brinjals not 1.

Comment: @quid: No, she doesn’t. That was merely an example illustrating what quantities are supposed to be equal; as noted in the parenthetical remark, it does not have the right quantities.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: what is in your opinion the price of 1 brinjal? And, why? In my opinion it is 0.05 rs as for 2rs she buys 40 (see at the start).

Comment: Correction to my original comment: I misread one line of the post. The second equation should be $0.05x+y+5z=100$, and there are two solutions, $x=80,y=1,z=19$ and $x=0,y=100,z=0$. The only thing requiring clarification is whether we’re to assume that the girl actually did buy at least one of each item.

Comment: @quid: Ah, you’re right about that: I misread that line. It changes the details but not the interpretation of the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: yes. And personally I'd say if anything it should be the solution where everything is positive after all it says she buys b *and* o *and* c suggesting that everything is actually bought. Though I am still idly wondering if the excercise is really correct as written, as it seems odd an eggplant is *that much* cheaper than an ognion. But that aside, I agree one can  understand and solve it as written.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y$, and $z$ be respectively the numbers of brinjals, onions, and coconuts bought. The requirement that $100$ items be bought means that $x+y+z=100$. If $40$ brinjals cost $2$ rupees, the cost of one brinjal is $\frac2{40}=0.05$ rupees. Each onion costs one rupee, and each coconut costs $5$ rupees, so the total cost is $0.05x+y+5z$. Thus, we want a solution in non-negative integers to the system

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&x+y+z=100\\
&0.05x+y+5z=100\;.
\end{align*}\right.\tag{1}$$

Multiply the second equation by $20$ to get $x+20z+100z=2000$ and subtract the first to get $19y+99z=1900$. Solving for $z$ in terms of $y$, we find that $$z=\frac{1900-19y}{99}=\frac{19}{99}(100-y)\;.$$

This is non-negative if and only if $y\le 100$, and since we also want $y\ge 0$, the only possible values of $y$ are the integers from $0$ through $100$. In order for $z$ to be an integer, $100-y$ must be a multiple of $99$, so either $y=100$, or $y=1$.

- If $y=100$, then $z=0$, and from $(1)$ we see that $x=0$ as well. One solution, then, is to buy $100$ onions and nothing else.
- If $y=1$, then $z=19$, and from $(1)$ we find that $x=80$: she can buy $80$ brinjals (for $4$ rupees), one onion (for $1$ rupee), and $19$ coconuts (for $95$ rupees).

If she is required to buy a non-zero amount of each of the three items, the only solution is the second one.

(For those who are unfamiliar with the term, *brindjal*, like *aubergine*, is another name for eggplant.)

Comment: Leave those rs and quantity .. but try to use the numbers by usin ratio and proportional

Comment: Guys even i am confused abt the question ill try to make it clear for you........ leave the rupees and the quantity ........ . use the numbers and their total should be 100... By using Ratio And Propotional

Comment: @chethana: I don’t see any way to solve it by applying ratios and proportionality to the original $40,1,5$ numbers; there is no solution that is a multiple of that set.